# Form Validation Error Message not showing

Tags: php, forms, validation

Was hoping for some fresh eyes on this. I've got a page which will add a new event to a database. All 3 fields are required, so if they are empty when the submit button is pushed the error message should appear. Anyone know why it isn't showing the error message? Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ADMIN - Repetative Strain Injury UK</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="/iis_project/view/css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- wrapper div for positioning -->
        <div class="grid10 first" id="header">
            <!-- Header Section -->
            <img src="/iis_project/view/img/banner.jpg" alt="RSI UK Banner" width="1090" height="75"/>
        </div>
        <div class="grid11 first" id="date">
            <!-- Date Section -->
            <?php
            include ("date.php");
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="grid2 first" id="col1">
            <!-- Left column Section -->
            <h1>Navigation</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="index.php"><strong>Home</strong></a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="aboutus.php"><strong>About Us</strong></a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="register.php"><strong>Register</strong></a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="login.php"><strong>Log In</strong></a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="events.php"><strong>Events</strong></a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="acknowledgements.php"><strong>Acknowledgements</strong></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid6" id="col2">
            <!-- Middle column Section -->
            <h1>New Event</h1>
            <p>

                As an admin you have the right to create a new event. Simply fill out the form below and hit submit.
            </p>
            <?php
// creates the new record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that         is easily reusable
function renderForm($name, $date, $location, $error22)
{

            ?>

            <?php
            // if there are any error22s, display them
            if ($error22 != '') {
                echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid     red; color:red;">' . $error22 . '</div>';
            }
            ?>

            <form action="" method="post">
                <div>
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" />
                    <br/>
                    Date:
                    <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date;?>" />
                    <br/>
                    Location:
                    <input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $location;?>" />
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit_event"     value="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>

<?php
}

   // connect to the database
 include ("home_connection.php");

  // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the form and    save it to the database
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
 $date = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']));
 $location = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['location']));
 // check to make sure all fields are entered
 if ($name == '' || $date == '' || $location == '')
 {
 // generate error22 message
 $error22 = 'error22: Please fill in all required fields!';

 // if either field is blank, display the form again
 renderForm($name, $date, $location, $error22);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT events SET name='$name', date='$date', location='$location'")
 or die(mysql_error22());

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: login_success_admin.php");
 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, display the form
 {
 renderForm('','','','');
 }
  ?>
  </div>
 <div class="grid2" id="col3">
<!-- Right column Section -->
<h1>Newsletter</h1>
<h2>Sign up to our newsletter:</h2>
<?php
include ("newsletter.php");
?>
   </div>
  <div class="grid10 first" id="footer">
<!-- Footer Section -->
<p>
    Repetative Strain Injury UK &copy; West Street, Jubille Way, Leeds, LS6  3QW. Email: <a href="info@rsiuk.org">info@rsiuk.org</a>
    Tel: 0113 658102. Reg charity no: 1032941
</p>
 </div>
 </div> <!-- end container -->
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I suggest to separate PHP from HTML to better understanding.

Comment: Try echoing out the variables after the form has been submitted to see if they do indeed have anything in them.  And you could always replace `if ($name == '' ||` etc with `if (strlen($name) < 1 ||` etc just to see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the submit name as "submit_event"
So you must  use

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_event'])) {
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />
```

to your form.  The $_POST array does not have a 'submit' value in the code you have provided, so it's just going to display the form again.